# ANTLR: Could not find symbol

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, javac

I have a ANTLR project called "Test.g4" and with antlrworks2 I created without any problems the files: Test.tokens, TestBaseListner.java, TestLexer.java, TestLexer.tokens, TestListener.java and TestParser.java.

Now I want to use the grammer in my program Test.java:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create a CharStream that reads from standard input
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);

        // create a lexer that feeds off of input CharStream
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(input);

        // create a buffer of tokens pulled from the lexer
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        // create a parser that feeds off the tokens buffer
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);

        ParseTree tree = parser.init(); // begin parsing at init rule
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser)); // print LISP-style tree
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it with `"javac -classpath /path/java2/antlr-4.4-complete.jar Test.java"` I get this errors:

```
Test.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(input);
        ^
  symbol:   class TestLexer
  location: class Test
Test.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(input);
                                        ^
  symbol:   class TestLexer
  location: class Test
Test.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
        ^
  symbol:   class TestParser
  location: class Test
Test.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
                                          ^
  symbol:   class TestParser
  location: class Test
4 errors
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you file is called `Sample.java` your class name must also be `Sample` not `Test`

Comment: Is TestLexer.java in same package as Test.java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestLexer.java` and `TestParser.java` should also be compiled with `Test.java` in the same command, otherwise the compiler will not know where to look for their binaries. Try calling `javac` as follows:

```
javac -classpath /path/java2/antlr-4.4-complete.jar *java
```

Or manually pass all files:

```
javac -classpath /path/java2/antlr-4.4-complete.jar Test.java TestLexer.java TestParser.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build and import lexer and parser generated by ANTLR. To do it you need to:

1. add import statement to a file with your main method
2. put classes generated by ANTLR into a package as in your import statement
3. build both generated classes and class with your main method